# How to have a action result return either a filestream or JSON back to view in MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an application using MVC 4. Currently I have a view where when the user clicks a button it posts the data back to an action method, that retrieves some data and returns a report based on that data to the user.

```
public ActionResult GetsData(DefectLetterCriteriaViewModel viewModel)
{
    .. get data code...
    using (FileStream templateStream = new FileStream(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefectLetterLocation"].ToString(), FileMode.Open))
    {
        .....generate document code
        return new FileStreamResult(outputDocumentStream, 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    }
}
```

This works well, the user gets a report of the data.  But what I want to do is if there is no data, I want to let the user know that there is no data, rather than return an empty report.

How do I achieve that? At the moment the user just posts the data back.. how can I get JSON data back from a post? Or do I have to use Ajax posting? If I am using Ajax posting how can I get a filestream result back from Ajax?

Comment: You need to do the posting via Ajax to get a handler of the response and display the info in JSON format. But never tryed what happends if you return a FileStream in a Ajax call. Did you?

Comment: You can test this approach from this question/answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178898/how-to-handle-filestream-return-type-in-ajax-post

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

```
if(no_data)
{
   //1.
   return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('No Data');</script>");

   //Or
   //2.
   string s = "alert('No Data');";   
   return JavaScript(s); 
}
```